How to calculate the probability of the joint distribution function of a c-vine copula within a given interval?
I have already computed a 6-dimensional joint distribution function in Python using the pyvinecopulib library and NumPy, and stored it in the variable cop. How can I calculate the probability on an interval such as
(0.5 < F1(X1) < 0.6, 0.5 < F2(X2) < 0.6, 0.5 < F3(X3) < 0.6, 0.5 < F4(X4) < 0.6, 0.5 < F5(X5) < 0.6, 0.6 < F1(X6) < 0.6)?
I have attempted to use cop.cdf(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6) - cop.cdf(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
For calculation, the results need to be corrected. Since these six variables represent wind and wave flow parameters, when I partition the intervals and sum the theoretical probabilities of all possible intervals, the sum of probabilities should ideally be

However, the sum of probabilities exceeds
How can I resolve this programming issue?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
